# No database selected error only comes up when in a separate included php config file but works when in needed file

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Basically ive been trying to create a config file so it is much easier to edit the MYSQL connection info to the online database when ive completed my current website. The connection code i have works perfectly when in each file when needed but when i try and use an required once on the same code in a config file it says no database selected. this error never happens when the connection code is pre written into files. here is my config file code and then the working code which is already on a working page.

config php

```
<?php
//configures connection to the mysql database.
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","james");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("cds", $con);    
?>
```

and here is the code on a working connection to the database

```
<?php
//configures connection to the mysql database.
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cds", $con);

$n = $_SESSION['news'];

// find out how many rows are in the table 
if($n == 1)
{
    echo '<h1>CDSRail News</h1>';
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news ORDER BY news_date DESC';
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<hr/>Click the links below to view our News<br><br>";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $numrows = $r[0];...
```

please help!!!

Comment: As I can se your username is different

Comment: MySQL username are different in both file. what is correct user name?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right approach for what are trying to do here. Your config file should do nothing but define variables, and you should do the actual connection in the main file. So you should do something like this:

config.php:

```
<?php

  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbUser = 'myuser';
  $dbPass = 'mypass';
  $dbName = 'mydbname';

?>
```

main.php

```
<?php

  require('config.php');
  if (!$con = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass)) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  if (!mysql_select_db($dbName, $con)) {
    die('Could not select database');
  }

  // Rest of code

?>
```